# How to have a try catch wait for response before continuing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, try-catch

I'm fetching some data from firestore and everything works, but there is one big flaw I'm trying to figure out…

I can only console log the data once I press on the “Read Data” button twice. Any help on how I can make it wait for it to have the response before showing it?

Bellow is my code, thanks in advance.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function ReadToFirebase() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])


    const readData = () => {
        try {
            firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                    let changes = snapshot.docChanges()
                    changes.forEach(change => {
                        let data = change.doc.data()
                        data = {
                            username: data.userName,
                            email: data.email
                        }
                        setData(oldArray => [...oldArray, data])
                    })
                })
            console.log('Data Read!')
            console.log(data);
            // return data
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Opps! Error querying data: \n\n ${error}`);
            alert(error)
        }
    }




    return (
        <div className="p-4 grid place-items-center space-y-2">
            <button onClick={readData} className="py-2 px-4 bg-gray-300 rounded-xl font-bold">Read Data</button>
            <div className="">{}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: onSnapshot happens asynchronously, probably. You need to wrap it in a promise and .then or await it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `console.log` statement is outside the `onSnapshot` function.
If you do something like this:

```
    const readData = () => {
        try {
            firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                    let changes = snapshot.docChanges()
                    changes.forEach(change => {
                        let data = change.doc.data()
                        data = {
                            username: data.userName,
                            email: data.email
                        }
                        setData(oldArray => [...oldArray, data])
                    });
            console.log('Data Read!')
            console.log(data);
                })

            // return data
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Opps! Error querying data: \n\n ${error}`);
            alert(error)
        }
    }
```

It'll work.

Two things to note here:

1. You can improve your code by using `map` instead of `forEach`:

```
const changedData = changes.map(change => {
                        let data = change.doc.data()
                        return {
                            username: data.userName,
                            email: data.email
                        }
                    });

setData(oldArray => [...oldArray, ...changedData])
```

2. In order for the `try/catch` to actually catch server error you should wrap your request in a promise. Something like:

```
const readData = () => {
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     firebase.firestore().collection('users').onSnapshot(handleSnapshot(resolve, reject)());
   })
   .then(handleSuccessfulUsersFetch)
   .catch(handleErrorInUsersFetch);
}
```

There are other ways you could achieve that (for instance with async/await).  You can read more about error handling in JS in this nice article:
https://medium.com/walkme-engineering/javascript-error-handling-9fc1a2946119